# Remove information from string using php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am trying to remove the following type of info from a string using php :

```
[url:2q57noz9]http&#58;//www&#46;mysite&#46;com/other/screencaps-from-ddd-t7099&#46;html#p24174[/url:2q57noz9]
```

there are random numbers assigned to the *[url:* bit which makes it harder. I tried to adapt the following which works for image tags but I don't think it likes square brackets put in like I have. This is what I used for images :

```
$message = preg_replace(array("/<img[^>]+\>/i","/<!--[^>]+\-->/i"), "", $message);
```

and this is how I tried to modify it without success :

```
$message = preg_replace("/[[^>]+\]/i", "", $message);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add backslash before brackets

```
$message = preg_replace('/\[[^>]+\]/i', "", $message);
```

and use single Quotation for holding string